# How to define a variable with timeout in C

Tags: c, time, timeout, pthreads

I need to define a variable and after 5 second, it must return to default value.

I'm thinking 2 different solutions but I didn't like these solutions because it is too much work for a simple problem and I'm looking better ways. ( BTW: I'm newbie with C )

**Solution 1:**
If I use a while loop, I can not continue until the while is over.
Do I have to call the function as a new pthread?
Are there any better simple solution?

```
void set_menu_timer(){
    timeout = 5;
    while (timeout != 0){
        timeout = timeout-1;
        HAL_Delay(1000);
    }
    current_menu = 0;
}
```

**Solution 2:**
When I define the variable, I'll also define the current timestamp to different variable and when I intented to use the value, I can check the current - old timestamp difference and if it's 5 second ahead then I wil not use the variable and set it to default value.
How can I do this?

Also, are there any better way?

Comment: Generally try to avoid sleep/delay for that reason. I like solution 2 since it is passive, and clean.  What platform are you on?  I've never seen `HAL_Delay`, but it makes it look like you are on an embedded platform.  If that is the case, your chip probably has timers that can be configured to interrupt at specific intervals.  You could use that to reset your variable.  A thread would also work.

Comment: Yes, HAL is the name of stm32 drivers.

Comment: There is a variaty of ways it could be done, but the specifics depend on what *exactly* you are trying to do. You can have a state machine with a fixed step time, so you just count the steps performed and switch the state where you reset the variable. Or you can have a timer interrupt, then you will set up when setting the variable, and reset it when the interrupt is firing. Or you can have a loop that will poll a timer value, and perform the actions based on it.